# is neither a launch file in package

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the Leddar ROS package using "roslaunch leddar leddar.launch serial:=serial frame:=frame_id fov:=fov range:=range" but it shows me that "[leddar.launch] is neither a launch file in package [leddar] nor is [leddar] a launch file name"

and I had try to put in the actual serial port number to run it : "roslaunch leddar leddar.launch serial:=ttyS0 frame:=frame_id fov:=fov range:=range " but it still shows me the same error.
got anyone face the same problem before and how to solve it?

*the ROS package i was git clone from github. https://github.com/mcgill-robotics/ros-leddar
*leddar@leddar-desktop:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.499748] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230774/is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-02**:
Have you built and sourced the catkin workspace where you have the leddar package?

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-03**:
Yes! I had built everything successfully but until to the running step shows this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like either you haven't built the package, or you haven't sourced your catkin workspace since building the package.

You can confirm that the package is correctly built and sourced by running `rospack find leddar`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-03**:
you are right, I just try to find the leddar package by running rospack find leddar  it shows that not found. So what can I do to source the package?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-03**:
After you've built your workspace with catkin_make, source it by running `source devel/setup.bash`

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-04**:
it shows me a new error said that failed to connect to serial with code: -1

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-04**:
I cannot use the github's running instruction to run the package it will shows me failed to connect to serial with code: -1
but I can use rosrun -v leddar leddar.launch to run the package.  when I open the rviz there have problem said that For fram[leddar]:Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-04**:
It sounds like you have resolved the original issue with being unable to find the launch file. You should probably open a new question about being unable to connect to the serial port. (these are very different topics)

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-04**:
ok.thanks.

**Comment by [trusktr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52857/trusktr/) on 2021-04-01**:
I'm having a similar issue. How do we run `source devel/setup.bash`? I mean, where is that file. That's a relative path, so it is not clear what folder to be in.

I think I have things installed, but I get the error regardless:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ apt list ros-melodic-rosbridge-*
Listing... Done
ros-melodic-rosbridge-library/bionic ...
ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs/bionic ...
ros-melodic-rosbridge-server/bionic ...
ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite/bionic ...

vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ rosdep db | grep rosbridge
rosbridge_suite -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite
rosbridge_server -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-server
rosbridge_msgs -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs
rosbridge_library -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-library

vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
RLException: [rosbridge_websocket.launch] is neither a launch file in package....
```

**Comment by [trusktr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52857/trusktr/) on 2021-04-01**:
I searched the system, and I do not see any `devel/setup.sh` file anywhere:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ locate ros | grep setup.sh
/opt/ros/melodic/local_setup.sh
/opt/ros/melodic/setup.sh
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/local_setup.sh.in
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.sh.in

vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ ls ~/catkin_ws
ls: cannot access '/home/vagrant/catkin_ws': No such file or directory
```

I installed everything with `apt-get`.

**Comment by [trusktr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52857/trusktr/) on 2021-04-02**:
Too late to delete my previous questions. I decided to ask a new question instead:

https://answers.ros.org/question/375225/rosbridge_websocketlaunch-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-rosbridge_server-nor-is-rosbridge_server-a-launch-file-name/